# How to switch from Fragment to Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Firstly I want to explain my problem,

1. I have `Slide menu` in my app. I have used
   android.support.v4.app.Fragment for that
2. I can move from fragment to activity easily.
3. My problem is how to move from Fragment to activity.

I tried the following code but no use.

```
FragmentManager fm = AddCaseFile.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
HospitalizationDetails fragment=new HospitalizationDetails();
ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment,fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Where `AddCaseFile` is my current activity

`HospitalizationDetails` is fragment (which i have to go)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fragment will be always inside activity. It can not stay along.Fragment is kind of view

Comment: navigate using [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: Thanks for ur response support_ms, how can i move to the fragment "HospitalizationDetails()" is there any way

Comment: @Kaushik i tried intent but it shows error

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{abts.mhv.mhvmobile/abts.mhv.mhvmobile.HospitalizationDetails}: java.lang.ClassCastException: abts.mhv.mhvmobile.HospitalizationDetails cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: I misunderstood your question for point `3` change it in question

Comment: now i changed kaushik

Comment: you say that you can move fragment to activity easily(No.2), but having trouble in moving fragment to activity(No.3). Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Just use `getActivity().startActivity()`, and the rest just like move activity to activity.
Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getActivity(), other.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: I try this in my code, it works fine with `OnClickListener()`.

Comment: working! but on/of both are work! how to make only "on" are work. Thanks

Comment: Works faboulously :)